# What order of power mean best estimates the median of a gamma distribution?

Tags: expected-value, error, gamma-distribution, estimators, median

Suppose we have a [gamma-distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) random variable $X$ whose shape/scale parameters are known to be $\alpha$ and $\beta$. What order $p$ for the sample [power mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) $\hat M_p[X]$ minimizes $$ (\mathcal{M}[X] - \hat M_p[X])^2 $$
where $\mathcal{M}[X]$ is the population median.

I suspect that the optimal choice of $p$ will depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I have not successfully worked out $p$ as a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Because the median and power mean are both properties of $X$, it makes no sense to apply an expectation operator to them.

Comment: @whuber Agreed! Fixed.

Comment: The answer varies slightly with shape but appears rapidly to approach a limit of $p=1/3$ (monotonically from below) as the shape increases.

Comment: Nice. This might be anticipated from the Wilson-Hilferty transformation - the cube root is used as a symmetrizing transformation for the gamma. It works well when the shape parameter is not small, but smaller $p$ is better when $\alpha$ is small.

Comment: @Glen_b Exactly--that made it easy to guess the approximate solution and study it quickly.